# Entity to Datamap/Array

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an Entity like that:

```
class Company extends AbstractEntity
{
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  protected $longName = '';

  //much more properties

  //all the setters and getters
}
```

I would like to use the `DataHandler` from the typo3 core to save such an Entity, because saving the entity should trigger the whole workspace mechanics, such that the updated Object/Entity/row is created as a new version. Extbase directly writes to the Database, what bypasses that.

Basically one can use the api like so:

```
$data = [
  'long_name' => 'some very long Name'
];

$cmd = [];
$cmd['tablename_for_entity']['uid_of_entity'] = $data;

$dataHandler->start($cmd, []);
$dataHandler->process_datamap();
```

So the Problem is to turn the Entity into a »DataMap« or appropriate array.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should also try to explain _why_ you intend to use the `DataHandler` instead of e.g. the native Extbase persistence.

Comment: Please see my updates…

Answer (score 1):

The reason for such a thing is a kind of a hack/workaround, to use the workspaces functionality from the frontend. That bypasses the database abstraction layer, which is very nice to have, just to trigger some hooks. I hope that this wont be needed in future releases but for now, I could solve it with this solution:

```
public function map(AbstractEntity $entity):array
{
  $result = [];

  $class = get_class($entity);

  /** @var ClassReflection $reflection */
  $reflection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ClassReflection::class, $class);

  /** @var DataMapper $mapper */
  $mapper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataMapper::class);

  $dataMap = $mapper->getDataMap($class);

  foreach ($entity->_getProperties() as $property => $value) {
    $colMap = $dataMap->getColumnMap($property);
    $reflProp = $reflection->getProperty($property);

    if (!is_null($colMap) and $reflProp->isTaggedWith('maptce')) {
      $result[$colMap->getColumnName()] = $mapper->getPlainValue($value, $colMap);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

That basically does something like `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Backend::persistObject()` and most of the code is taken from there as well. But the general Data mapping especially for nested Entities and so on is would have been too complex for now, so I decided to just test if a property has an `@maptce` annotation to simplify the process.

It is no Problem to skip some properties since the TCE `process_datamap()` method will care about that.

Comment: In addition to the statement `no Problem to skip some properties since the TCE process_datamap() method will care about that`:

Attention for database strict mode: In case properties don't have a default value in the SQL schema definition this will trigger an error when inserting records. It can be solved be defining additional `default` values in TCA. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542151/typo3-sql-error-incorrect-integer-value-for-column-sys-language-uid-at/50138799#50138799 for further details

Comment: good to know, thanks. my dive into the source wasn't that deep :)