# TYPO3 set uid to new model

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

Simple question: how to set uid to new model? TYPO3 8.7.17. 
I tried adding method

```
public function setUid($uid)
{
   $this->uid = $uid;
}
```

I assume I am creating a custom extension and I want to save the uid in a new model
But model not saving. I know it is not recommend. But I have causes why I need it.

I need id because user make import of data from csv every day. And I have relative data. When user make import uids are changing. I can't assign the date as well.

Comment: I assume you are creating a custom extension and you want to save the uid in a model, aren't you?

Comment: exactly what I need

Comment: You should elaborate on the _causes why [you] need it_. Otherwise we cannot be sure that there is or isn't a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `uid` is not possible that easily, but you can use the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper` to create the entity instance from a given data array.

```
$data = [
  'uid' => 10101,
  'title' => 'Foo Bar Baz',
  …
];

$dataMapper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)
                ->get(DataMapper::class);

$obj = reset($dataMapper->map(YourModel::class, [data]));
```

Or you just create a new Instance of the Model and use [Reflection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php) to change the uid property:

```
$obj = new YourEntity();
$refl = new ReflectionClass(YourEntity::class);

$refl->getProperty('uid')->setValue($obj, '10101');
```

In case of an Import I would prefer the former way, since you somehow need to map the data to the instance and that is what the DataMapper is for.

For the other way around you might have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395532/entity-to-datamap-array)

Comment: How to store the object with the manipulated uid in the DB? I tried via Repository but the uid is never set...

Comment: Honestly,  gave up using typo3, its just madness, I am happy that I have forgotten about this issue ;)

Comment: Well, while Extbase is still sometimes anoing, TYPO3 is getting cleaner and better each version. For huge CMS platforms its IMHO the best option out there. To come around this issue I used my own query - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From t3 8 on you can (should) use doctrine:

```
$connectionPool=GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
$queryBuilder = $connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
$queryBuilder
    ->insert($table)
    ->values([
       'name' => $name,
       'crdate' => time(),
       'pid' => $pid,
       'uid' => $uid        
])
->execute();
```

Simple and standard. Even in t3.

Answer (score 0):

The function `setUid()` exists in the model already if I don't mistake, usually it's just in the class that you extend by your own model-class.
So you can use probably already `setUid()` without writing it in your own model-class.

The main problem is that `uid` is an `auto_increment`, index and primary key, so you've to assure that new values for uid are always unique.
Also the individual usage of `setUid()` might be still blocked somehow in TYPO3.

For import-related challenges there exists the extension [external_import](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/external_import/), that might be  what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a simple row query like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query(
            'INSERT INTO my_table (uid,title,pid)
              VALUES ('.$id.',"'.$title.'",'.$storagePid.')'
        );
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this shouldn't work upon t3 9+ ??…

Comment: Right, unless you install the "typo3db_legacy" Extension $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] is not supported anymore in V9.

Comment: and there goes the t3 madness… I came over this, because I wanted to clone an object, I thought that this wasn't too much to ask for, but in t3 you just can't unless you hack or have extensions…