# TYPO3 6.2 Error - cant create new articles (Incorrect integer value)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

Since I moved from MySQL to MariaDB I can not create any new NEWS acticle anymore.

Error is: `2: SQL error: 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'SITE'.'tx_news_domain_model_news'.'sys_language_uid' at row 1' (tx_news_domain_model_news:NEW5f0c778d539382.63899223)`

I already have read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50138799 and also applied the changes but I did not solve the problem.

Seems like it needs to be integer but is string. Anyone facing the same issue?
Or even does have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok got it. If someone is on TYPO3 v6.2 you will mostly not find any good answer anymore as its not supported anymore and most people are not using it anymore.

However the solution is:

set:

```
[SYS][setDBinit] = SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Or go to **LocalConfiguration.php** and set:

```
'SYS' => 'setDBinit' => 'SET SESSION sql_mode = \'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION\';',
```

Or simply add:

```
'setDBinit' => 'SET SESSION sql_mode = \'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION\';',
```

to already existing 'SYS' configs.